# Porting C++ code from MS Visual Studio to Linux and dealing with typed enums

Tags: c++, linux, enums, g++

I am porting code that was written with MS Visual Studio.  For enums MS Visual Studio allows a user to specify a type like this:

enum SystemStatus : BYTE { Ok = 0, NeedsAttention, Failed };

where BYTE is unsigned char

Reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dzy4k6e.aspx

This causes errors when I try and compile the code with g++ version 4.1.2 that comes with RedHat 5.6.  Apparently the new C++ standard C++0x supports strongly typed enumerations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Strongly_typed_enumerations

Is there an easy way to solve this problem and get the code ported?  If possible we would like the code to compile in both Windows and Linux.  The number of enums in this project is huge!! Thanks.

Comment: Do you have to use such an old compiler? GCC 4.6.1 accepts this in C++0x mode. Building the compiler from source is also very easy.

Comment: The syntax is fairly simple for enums so you could process the source code files with a patterned search and replace.

Comment: I could move to RHEL 6 (or CentOS 6) which comes with GCC 4.4, would that do the trick?

Comment: Here is a list of supported C++0x features for gcc http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of g++ you are using doesn't support c++11 features, such as extended enums. Just compile latest g++ from source, there is a [helper script](http://advogato.org/person/redi/diary/229.html) that downloads gcc dependencies and builds it for you.

Comment: Hmm but how's the C++ ABI compatibility these days? Can you link c++ code compiled with 4.6 with a system library compiled with 4.1? Of course, if all support libs he uses are C, it's a non issue.

Comment: 4.6 should be compatible with versions starting from 3.4. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html has not been updated to include 4.6 though.

Comment: I upgraded to CentOS6 and that solved the problem after I included "-std=c++0x" for g++ compiler flags.  Thanks for the help.